# Resharper fasle error 'Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: parameter type mismatch'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Using VS2015 and R# 2017.2.1 (exact version below), Typescript 2.5.2

I see R# shows false errors in VS although the code compiles fine.

`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: parameter type mismatch`

The typical sample is definition of AngularJS controller. The interface for controller is defined in a way that it has all members optional and I suppose that's the reason why R# is not able to validate the type (if I add some of `IController` interface's optional members (e.g. `$onInit?(): void`) to my controller class, the error disappears).

Is there a way how to avoid this kind of false errors (other than adding the members I actually don't implement or disabling Typescript feature in R# options)?

`JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2017.2.1  Build 109.0.20170920.170950
ReSharper 2017.2.20170921.75418
Visual Studio 2015 (version 14.0.25431.1)`

Comment: Just discovered bug report here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466368 Anyway, I'd keep it here as the google search works pretty well for SO